# Find print queue name by IP address

Tags: network-printers

So, I'm working with something fun. Whoever set up a lot of printers in my office didn't register them in our DNS tools, so it's impossible to reverse look up the printers by their supposed print queue name. All I have are serials, MAC addresses, model names, and IP addresses. What I don't have is a list of all possible devices these printers are attached to, so I can't look them up by that, either.

Is there a way to look up print queue names by IP, MAC, or serial number? If there's a search in Active Directory or something I can enter in command line/make a bat file, or powershell script...I'll take anything, I don't care what it is. I'm drawing a complete blank. They're all network print servers and they all have embedded print servers.

Comment: Can you add the printers like this - https://comphelp.chem.wisc.edu/content/how-do-i-add-printer-if-i-know-its-ip-address ?

Comment: I don't even need to add them, I just need to look up their information.